# Invalid use of group function (MySQL)

Tags: mysql

[image]

why did it happen? I don't understand "where" is wrong.

Comment: dont have avg in the where clause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `AVG` function without grouping. You either use `GROUP BY` and include `AVG` in `SELECT` or in your case, use:

```
SELECT StudentID 
FROM Scores
WHERE score >= (SELECT AVG(score) FROM Scores);
```

Comment: Thanks! It was very helpful for me.

Comment: I am glad it was helpful. If this answer helped to resolve your issue, please mark it as accepted answer.